# php file upload ( some photos are ignored )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the next block of code. It works fine, but some photos(JPEG) are just ignored.Also I'm not sure if I displayed the messages well ( I'm using AJAX and I need to display that messages in callback function ).

```
$file = $_FILES['settingsListUlLiBackgroundImageUploadHeader1'];
$allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);
$detectedType = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
$image_info = getimagesize($file["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];
if(strtolower(in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes))){
    if($image_width < 4000 && $image_height < 4000){
        if ($file["size"] < 2097152){
            if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], 'images/'.$file['name'])){
                echo json_encode(['message' => 'Uploaded']);    
            }else{
                echo json_encode(['message' => 'Unable to move image. Is folder writable?']); 
                die();      
            }
        }else{
            echo json_encode(['message' => 'File size cannot be bigger than 2MB']); 
            die(); 
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode(['message' => 'File size cannot be bigger than 4000x4000']); 
        die();
    }
}else{    
    echo json_encode(['message' => 'Please upload only png, jpg images']); 
    die(); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ignored? is there any message/error outputted?

Comment: No, aren't uploaded and I don't get any error message. For some images this works fine, but for others don't.

Comment: do a `var_dump($detectedType)` and post what it gives in the question, and why are you using `strtolower()`?

Comment: for some images i get the 'Updated' message, for other I get the error message and for other (which are ignored) i get the next errors  : Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in on line 5
Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in on line 6 and var_dump for $detectedType returns
bool(false)

Comment: Your code actually makes no sense, you may want to look for a tutorial on how to upload files.

Comment: Ok, I thought it's not so bad, but I apreciate your honesty. Thanks for your time!